# Is it possible to replace strong tag with B in the default rich text editor of Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to modify the strong tag which renders in the rich text editor of sitecore.

When I select Core DB and go to the following path I can see the Bold Item as below :-

[image]

However I am not sure how and from where the sitecore existing code is rendering that  tag when the B is clicked in RTE. Is it possible on configuration level only or do I need to override any method customizing the pipeline as well ?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using? My instance inserts <strong> tags without any customization.

Answer (score 2):

According to the HTML 5 specification, the `<b>` tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate. The HTML 5 specification states that headings should be denoted with the `<h1>` to `<h6>` tags, emphasized text should be denoted with the `<em>` tag, important text should be denoted with the `<strong>` tag, and marked/highlighted text should use the `<mark>` tag.

However back to your question - Sitecore is using Telerik RTE. I tried to search js or config files where tags are applied to click event but couldn't find anything. Therefore I think there is no easy way how to update tag definition which is linked to particular button.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis on this.

Answer (score 0):

`<strong>` tags should be the default behaviour. At least in Sitecore 9 it appears to be. As mentioned in the other answer, that is preferable to the `<b>` tag.

If not, according to [this article](https://blog.thesparktree.com/customize-the-rich-text-editor-in-sitecore) you may need to override a class that inherits from `Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorConfiguration`.

```
public class RichTextEditorCustomConfiguration: Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorConfiguration
{
    public RichTextEditorCustomConfiguration(Item profile)
        : base(profile)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetupFilters()
    {
        //Disable the automatic conversion of <i> and <b> tags to <em> and <strong> for icon-* classes
        this.Editor.DisableFilter(EditorFilters.FixUlBoldItalic);
        this.Editor.DisableFilter(EditorFilters.MozEmStrong);
        this.Editor.EnableFilter(EditorFilters.IndentHTMLContent);

        // If using Sitecore 8.1
        // this.Editor.DisableFilter(EditorFilters.ConvertTags);      

        base.SetupFilters();
    }
}
```

Then add this setting:

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultConfigurationType" value="MyProject.RichTextEditorCustomConfiguration, MyProject"></setting>
```

This question also points out something interesting. There is a discrepancy between the tag that gets applied when bolding in line vs. in the rich text popup window. Inline, it applies `<b>`. In the popup, it applies `<strong>`. For those wanting consistent tag applications, the inline buttons should be disabled, or you should `DisableWebEdit` on the field and force the user to use the popup editor via an edit frame.

Comment: Hi Marcel, I tried the provided custom code however I was still getting the <strong> tag rendered for Bold button in RTE. We are using Sitecore 9.2 . Please find the screenshot below :-

Comment: Another observation is that this only works whenever I am giving Bold from inline editing of RTE. If I am selecting Bold from within the RTE pop-up window, it is still giving me the Strong tag, also at the time of page load the strong tag is getting rendered.